# ejabberd module compilation error

Tags: windows, server, erlang, ejabberd, erlang-shell

I am new to ejabberd, trying to add new module for offline_message_posturl, on a Windows server. I couldn't find any blog post specifically for Windows other than the below. I am using ejabberd version 15.07.

I have been following this blog post: 
http://jasonrowe.com/2011/12/30/ejabberd-offline-messages/

Right now I am not able to create a `.beam` file from the module file. I get this error:

```
> c(mod_http_offline).     
mod_http_offline.erl:21: undefined macro 'INFO_MSG/2'     
mod_http_offline.erl:27: undefined macro 'INFO_MSG/2' 
mod_http_offline.erl:44: undefined macro 'INFO_MSG/2'   
mod_http_offline.erl:11: function start/2 undefined  
mod_http_offline.erl:11: function stop/1 undefined  
mod_http_offline.erl:38: function post_offline_message/3 undefined  
error
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `INFO_MSG` macro used to be defined in the header file `ejabberd.hrl`, but it was moved to `logger.hrl` in ejabberd 13.06, which was released after that blog post was written.  Include `logger.hrl` as well as `ejabberd.hrl`, and your file should compile:

```
-include("ejabberd.hrl").
-include("logger.hrl").
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. i am able to build the .beam file. and copied to "ebin" folder. and added the "mod_http_offline: []" under modules section in ejabberd.yml file and restarting i am getting error still. As per the blog suppose to add in

Comment: I am still facing error while restarting the ejabberd server. in blog it has said module has to add in cfg file, but for new version to my knowledge configuration has to be in .yml file without { }

Answer (score 1):

You are not pointing to ejabberd include .hrl file. Simplest approach is probably to add you module to ejabberd src directory and recompile everything.

Otherwise, you can compile your module with erlc using -I to point to ejabberd include dirs (use as many -I directive as needed). For example:

```
erlc -I ../ejabberd/include mod_http_offline.erl
```